# React.JS State persistence for switch on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state, persistence

I am trying to have my toggle switch persist its state upon a page refresh in React.JS. I have looked into local storage but I am not sure how to implement it correctly.

Currently, I am creating a toggle switch in semantic and adding it as a component in my subheader.

This is my toggle switch component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react'

type Props = {
    label : string
}

class ToggleSwitch extends React.Component<Props> {
    state = { status: false }
    render() {
        return (
            <Checkbox
                onClick={() => this.setState({ status: !status })}
                label={this.props.label}        
                toggle

            />
        );
    }
}

export default ToggleSwitch;
```

This is my subheader class where I am calling the component

```
import * as React from "react";
import ToggleSwitch from './new_layout/ToggleSwitch'




interface Props {
    name: string;
  renderAction?: () => any;
}



const SubHeader: React.SFC<Props> = ({ name, renderAction }) => {
    return (
        <div className="settings-submenu">
            <div className="settings-submenu-name">{name}</div>
            <div className="settings-submenu-name">{renderAction && renderAction()}</div>
            <ToggleSwitch label = "Enable New Layout"/>

        </div>
  );
};

export default SubHeader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by:

1. Checking on componentDidMount or useEffect hook (I recommend you use functional components and hooks for your case) the toggle key on the localStorage.
2. If it exists, load it, if not, create it.
3. Handle the setToggle in a separate function to update the localState and the localStorage.

Here:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "semantic-ui-react";

type Props = {
  label: string;
};

function ToggleSwitch(props: Props) {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // check when the component is loaded
    const localStorageToggled = localStorage.getItem("toggled");

    // If is not null
    if (localStorageToggled) {
      setToggle(localStorageToggled === "true" ? true : false);
    } else {
      // If null set the localStorage key/value as a string.
      localStorage.setItem("toggle", `${toggle}`);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleToggle = (toggle: boolean) => {
    localStorage.setItem("toggle", `${toggle}`);
    setToggle(toggle);
  };
  return (
    <Checkbox
      onClick={() => handleToggle(!toggle)}
      label={props.label}
      toggle
    />
  );
}

export default ToggleSwitch;
```

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-einstein-jy6h3?file=/src/new_layout/ToggleSwitch.tsx:0-883
Video: https://streamable.com/0nkgub